# Google Chrome randomly shuffles SVG images in <object> tags

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have an HTML page with many `<object>` tags, each including a different SVG image.

Example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="first.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="totally-different.svg"></object>
```

In Google Chrome, the page initially displays as expected. However, if I browse away from the page, then return using the back/forward buttons, the SVG images are shuffled: they can appear inside the wrong `<object>` tag.

Example:
On first view, the page appears as per the markup:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="first.svg">
  <!-- first.svg will appear here -->
</object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="totally-different.svg">
  <!-- totally-different.svg will appear here -->
</object>
```

After back/forward, the images may be swapped

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="first.svg">
  <!-- totally-different.svg will appear here! -->
</object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="totally-different.svg">
  <!-- first.svg will appear here! -->
</object>
```

How do I prevent this erroneous behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, [#352762](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352762), in Blink, Chromium's rendering engine. At this time a patch has been submitted, but the bug is not yet fixed in the release version.

A workaround for the current release version is to add a `name` attribute to each of the `<object>` tags:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="first.svg" name="first">
</object>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="totally-different.svg"
  name="totally-different">
</object>
```

In this case, Chrome will correctly identify the SVG file in its cache, and not simply assign a random cached SVG file every time it comes across an `<object>` tag.

Comment: This bug affects Chrome 34, and is fixed in version 35 (currently in beta release).

Comment: @ErikDahlström do you know when v35 is scheduled for release? [Chromium dev calendar](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar) suggests it's scheduled for about one month ago

Comment: Still a bug in v.48 (March, 2016). @Jeremy - very big THANK YOU for the solution, it works, but just out of curiosity - how did you find it out? It's not very intuitive/obvious...

Comment: Never mind, I can see it in comments on the bug report page :)

Comment: @konrad_firm thanks for filing the new bug report with chromium, if that was you. Maybe they can just re-use the same patch to fix it.

Comment: @Jeremy you're welcome:) BTW: I think that Google just doesn't care about supporting svg in their browser. It's the only browser, in which the svg files load with a delay, that is, one after another (but quickly), at least on my machine. IE and FF work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely this seems to still happen in the current release (43). I had assumed that this was a more general bug with the object tag, since all of mine have unique ID attributes. It appears that the bug only goes away if you use the name attribute - which is a little ironic, given that ID has to be unique!